# Did a Mac update ruin my ability to use gcc?

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I am trying to compile two c files into one executable. In the directory I have only three files; Makefile, main.c and myfunction.c.

Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O0
LIBS = -lm
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
MAIN = main

all: $(MAIN)
    @echo  Program has been compiled

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void myfunc();
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    myfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

myfunction.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void myfunc() { printf("hello world"); }
```

output after make:

```
gcc -Wall -g -O0   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -g -O0   -c -o myfunction.o myfunction.c
gcc -Wall -g -O0  -o main main.o myfunction.o -lm
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_myfunc", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I had something nearly identical working in the past. I have since clean installed MacOS and updated to Big Sur. Is this the issue or have I overlooked something?

Comment: what is the output of `gcc -v`

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Remove all output files (`*.o` and `main`), then compile those files directly in one compiler invocation: `clang -o main main.c myfunction.c`. The makefile you're using looks OK-ish - the wildcards are bad practice even if they happen to work this very moment. They will bite you exactly when it'd be helpful to have them (as the project grows). The makefile as it stands doesn't make much sense for C projects smaller than 100k lines at the very least - compiling C is ridiculously fast these days, especially at `-O0`. Call the compiler once and be done with it. Yes, you can do it from a Makefile.

Comment: BTW, if you didn't notice: there's no gcc on your system, so it couldn't get broken :) It's just an alias to `clang`, so you may as well be direct about it - in case that said alias somehow got misconfigured. `gcc -v` really means `clang -v`, and so on. I'm not sure how long ago Apple stopped providing `gcc` for MacOS, but it has probably been a decade at least?

Comment: I also presume that you've invoked `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` from the command line?

Comment: I had no clue about gcc being the alias for clang. I'm a mathematician trying to learn this programming stuff. I ran as you said but got this:     $ clang -o main main.c myfunction.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_myfunc", referenced from:
      _main in main-8480ac.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I rad sudo xcodebuild -license accept before $ clang -o main main.c myfunction.c

Comment: check that myfunction.c actually has the code you posted, and not some silly typo or unsaved?

Comment: No typo, I even tried making a separate file with a different function just to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything. Same result

Comment: Run `nm` on both `.o` files, to see what they want/provide exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I’m not sure what part fixed it, but installed Homebrew and used it to install gcc-10. I also deleted the project and started over.

Answer (score -2):

myfunc would define like file header

**myfunc.h**

```
void myfunc()
```

Declare in another file

**myfunc.c**

```
void myfunc() { printf("hello world"); }
```

Follow the following tutorial

https://developer.gnome.org/anjuta-build-tutorial/stable/build-make.html.en

Comment: The question asker has done exactly that. This answer doesn't add anything new, and doesn't explain much.